# Quote a special character in a script file using awk

Tags: linux, awk, quoting

So I'm looking to write a script file which takes in a user-inputed number, and based off that number, it will execute a certain command. This command is the `awk` command that, of course, uses a field separator. I'm using `awk` on the following file `/etc/passwd`:

```
smiths|Login|2
olivert|Login|2
northj|Login|2
denniss|Login|2
smithd|Login|2
smiths|Time Reporting|210
olivert|Payroll|155
northj|Server Maintenance|70
northj|Logfile Reporting|45
denniss|Report Printing|80
smithd|Payroll Program Updates|150
smithd|Payroll Program Updates|180
smiths|Logout|2
olivert|Logout|2
northj|Logout|2
denniss|Logout|2
smithd|Logout|2
```

My issue is that I'm trying to use the pipe as the field separator, but when I try backslash-escaping the pipe (which is what I think I'm supposed to do), it's not actually quoting it. If I use something like a colon, it's fine:

```
case "$choice" in
    1)
       awk -F : '$2\n'
       ;;
    2)
       awk -F : '$1\n'
       ;;
```

Instead of the colon, I'm looking to use the pipe (refer to the file above) as the field separator. Any answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax is `awk '-F[|]' '{ print $2 }'`

The `|` is a **shell** special character, so it needs quoting to prevent shell trying to make a pipeline.

But `|` is also an **awk** special character, used to separate alternate patterns in a regular expression. Best way to quote that is to make it into a range consisting of a single character, as `[|]`. The -F option sets the awk variable FS (Field Separator), which is used as a regular expression (RE, pattern).

Then the whole thing needs quoting, because `[..]` can also be a shell special character, which expands filenames.

`'$2\n'` is a valid awk program, but it does not do what you expect. It is in the position of a pattern with no action. So if $2 is non-blank, the pattern is just True, and the whole line gets printed.

You want an action, which is what the `{ }` does, and you want to select just one field and print it. It does not need a newline -- print does that automatically.

Comment: Isn't `FS` only used as a regular expression if it's longer than a single character?  Using `-F '|'` or `-F \|` should work as expected. The issue is probably rather with the actual code.

Comment: The GNU/awk guide does say a single-char FS is not an RE (ignoring the one-space case), which is reasonable because it is hard to make an RE one character long. So you're right (again). But I have seen `-F' *|'` used to set FS to trim trailing blanks off all fields, and that really does no good. So I generally am very conservative in making a charset of anything that might be a special character in other circumstances. I also don't know just which awk the OP is using, and his current quoting does not work, and I just prefer to recommend a one-shot fix to problems.

Comment: GNU `awk` follows the POSIX spec in this regard. A space is special, but any other single character should be taken as exactly that character, and not as a regular expression.

Comment: I didn't spot the OPs Linux tag, but he still might be in mawk. I'm aware that SunOS and AIX awk can be non-conforming (plenty pain in the past, including not permitting a space between -F and the character). I said you're right about the single char, but mine works too and is less likely to be broken by maintenance. For the record, I prefer BEGIN { FS = ... } for any significant script, because I like the FS not to be detached into the command line, which may be some distance away.